# A Necessary Condition for an Extremum with Constraint

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I was reading Zorich's book about Lagrange multiplier method. When I read the theorem I ran into few questions which I was not able to answer myself even though I tried hard.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open set $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and belonging to $C^1(D;\mathbb{R})$.
> Let $S$ be a smooth surface in $D$.  A necessary condition for a point
> $x_0\in S$ that is noncritical for $f$ to be a  local extremum of
> $\left.f\right|_S$ is that $$TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0},$$ where
> $TS_{x_0}$ is the tangent space to the surface $S$ at $x_0$ and
> $TN_{x_0}$ is the  tangent space to the level surface $N = \{x \in D: f(x) = f(x_0)\}$ of $f$ to which  $x_0$ belongs.
>
> *Remark:* We begin by remarking that the requirement that the point $x_0$ be noncritical for $f$ is not an essential restriction in the
> context of the problem of finding an extremum with constraint, which
> we are discussing. Indeed, even if the point $x_0\in D$ were a
> critical point of the function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ or an extremum of
> the function, it is clear that it would still be a possible or actual
> extremum respectively for the function $\left.f\right|_S$. Thus, the
> new element in this problem is precisely that the function
> $\left.f\right|_S$ may have criticial points and extrema that are
> different from those of $f$.
>
> *Proof.* We choose an arbitrary vector $\xi\in TS_{x_0}$ and a smooth path $x=x(t)$ on $S$ that passes through this point at $t=0$ and for
> which the vector $\xi$ is the velocity at $t=0$, that is,
> $$\frac{dx}{dt}(0)=\xi. \quad \quad \quad (8.162)$$ If $x_0$ is an
> extremum of the function $\left.f\right|_S$, the smooth function
> $f(x(t))$ must have an extremum at $t=0$. By the necessary condition
> for an extremum, its derivative must vanish at $t=0$, that is, we must
> have $$f'(x_0)\cdot \xi=0, \quad \quad \quad (8.163)$$ where
> $f'(x_0)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1},\dots,\frac{\partial
>  f}{\partial x^n}), \quad \xi=(\xi^1,\dots,\xi^n).$ Since $x_0$ is a
> noncritical of $f$, condition $(8.163)$ is equivalent to the condition
> $\xi\in TN_{x_0}$, for relation $(8.163)$ is precisely the equation of
> the tangent space $TN_{x_0}$. Thus we have proved that
> $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$. $\Box$
>
> If the surface $S$ is defined by the system of equations $(8.160)$ in a
> neighborhood of $x_0$, then the space $TS_{x_0}$, as we know, is
> defined by the system of linear equations $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^1}(x_0)\xi^1+\dots+\frac{\partial
>  F^1}{\partial x^n}(x_0)\xi^n=0,\\ \cdots\cdots\cdots\\ \frac{\partial
>  F^m}{\partial x^1}(x_0)\xi^1+\dots+\frac{\partial F^m}{\partial
>  x^n}(x_0)\xi^n=0. \end{cases} \quad \quad \quad (8.164)$$ The space
> $TN_{x_0}$ is defined by the equation $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  x^1}(x_0)\xi^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}(x_0)\xi^n=0,
>  \quad \quad \quad (8.165)$$ and, since every solution of $(8.164)$ is
> a solution of $(8.165)$, the latter equation is a consequence of
> $(8.163)$.
>
> It follows from these considerations that the realtion
> $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$ is equivalent to the analytic statement
> that the vector $\text{grad}f(x_0)$ is a linear combinatrion of the
> vectors $\text{grad}F^i(x_0),\ (i=1,\dots,m)$, that is,
> $$\text{grad}f(x_0)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i\text{grad}F^i(x_0).$$

My questions are as follows:

1. Why do we assume that $x_0\in S$ is a noncritical point of $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$? Is that so important? Actually, Zorich gives some explanation before the proof but I read it about 10 times and it is written very sloppy and very unclear.
2. So we have that $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$? Why does it imply that $\text{grad}f(x_0)$ is a linear combination of $\text{grad}F^1(x_0),\dots,\text{grad}F^m(x_0)$?

I'd be very grateful if someone can give a clear explanation to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:**

Zorich's remark is indeed a bit unclear. What he wants to say is this.

There are two alternatives for a point $x_0 \in S$:

**Alternative 1.** $x_0$ is a critical point of $f$.

Note that in general not all critical points of $f$ will lie in $S$, but all points outside of $S$ are irrelevant for the purpose of finding extrema of $f \mid_S$.

As a critical point of $f$, $x_0$ satisfies the necessary condition for being an extremum of $f$ (see Theorem 5 on p.463). We can next check whether $x_0$ is an extremum of $f$. A sufficient  criterion is given in Theorem 6 on p.464.

If $x_0 \in S$ is an extremum of $f$, then it is a fortiori also an extremum of $f \mid_S$ and we are done.

If $x_0 \in S$ is not an extremum of $f$, then some work is left to check whether it is an extremum of $f \mid_S$. Zorich does not offer a general theorem for such a check.

Anyway, the critical points of $f$ which lie in $S$ are good candidates for extrema of $f \mid_S$.

**Alternative 2.** $x_0$ is a noncritical point of $f$.

Then Theorem 1 gives a necessary condition for $x_0$ being an extremum of $f \mid_S$.

This explains why he considers only noncritical points of $f$ in Theorem 1. The critical points of $f$ have already been handled in alternative 1.

Thus the recipe is

1. Determine the critical points of $f$.
2. If such a critical point lies in $S$, check whether $f$ has an extremum at this point. If not, check whether $f \mid_S$ has an extremum at this point.
3. Consider the points $x_0 \in S$ which are noncritical points of $f$ and apply Theorem 1.

Note that the proof of Theorem 1 requires that $f'(x_0) \ne 0$ because a tangent space $TN_{x_0}$ is only defined for such $x_0$ (see Definition 2 on p.523 and work through the following pages).

Observe that if $f'(x_0) = 0$, then (8.165) *formally* yields $TN_{x_0} = \mathbb R^n$ which does not make sense to be regarded as a tangent space of a level surface of $f$. But even if we would do that, it does not make sense to consider the case $f'(x_0) = 0$ in Theorem 1 because then $TS_{x_0} \subset TN_{x_0}$ is trivially satisfied and therefore no reasonable necessary condition is obtained.

**Q2:**

Equation (8.165) means that $\operatorname{grad} f(x_0)$ is in the orthogonal complement $TN^\bot_{x_0}$ of $TN_{x_0}$ and (8.164) means that the vectors $\operatorname{grad} F^i(x_0)$ form as basis of the orthogonal complement $TS^\bot_{x_0}$ of $TS_{x_0}$. Since $TS_{x_0} \subset TN_{x_0}$, we have $TN^\bot_{x_0} \subset TS^\bot_{x_0}$. This proves the theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am reading it now. One question: you mentioned some criterion in Theorem 6 on page 454. I cannot find this in my book. Can you clarify it please?

Comment: @ZFR It was a typ. See my update.

Comment: Dear Paul, I read your post many times (especially the part which answer Question 1) but I am still confused.  Theorem 1 says that "if something holds, then $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$". You said that "thus the case that $x_0$ is a critical point of $f$ has been already covered". Do you mean that Theorem 1 is still true if $x_0$ is a critical point of $f$? Sorry but I still can understand your answer to Q1.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I will read it. Just a quick comment: you said that Theorem 1 does not claim that $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$ under certain conditions. Why not? Theorem 1 says that if $x_0$ is a noncritial point of $f$ and $x_0\in S$ is an extremum of $f|_S$ then $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$. This means that it tells us that $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$ under certain conditions. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @ZFR You are right, I have written nonsense. A necessary conditon is the implication of something you want to have.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused: author considers $TN_{x_0}$ which is a tangent space to submanifold $N=\{x\in D: f(x)=f(x_0)\}$ at point $x_0$. But why $N$ is a manifold actually? In order to show that it is a manifold we need to show that for any $a\in N$ there exist its neighborhood $U(a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and diffeomorphism $\varphi:U(a)\to (-1,1)^n$ such that $\varphi(U(a)\cap N)=(-1,1)^{n-1}\times \{0\}$. Probably it should be $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold but I do not see how to prove it.

Comment: @ZFR This is a completely new question. Please ask in a separate post.

Comment: Before accepting your answer I'd like to ask you the final question: So we were able to prove that a necessary condition for an extremum wth constraint is $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$ and of course here we assumed that $x_0\in S$ is a noncritical point of $f$, i.e., $\nabla f(x_0)\neq \vec{0}$. Then Zorich shows that $TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0}$ is equivalent to $\nabla f(x_0)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\nabla \lambda_i F^i(x_0)$.

Comment: Taking this into account I think we can formulate the necessary condition as follows: if the point $x_0\in S$ is a local extremum of $f|_S$, then $\nabla f(x_0)\in \text{span}(\nabla F^1(x_0),\dots,\nabla F^1(x_0)).$ Notice that in this formulation we can remove the condition that $x_0$ is a noncritical point of $f$. Is my reasoning correct? Thank you!

Comment: @ZFR Question in first comment: Yes. Question in second comment: Yes. But if $x_0$ is a critical point, then this is trivial because $\nabla f(x_0) = 0$ and you will not get a reasonable information from it.

Comment: Yes, if $\nabla f(x_0)=0$, then the statement $\nabla f(x_0)\in \text{span}(\nabla F^1(x_0),\dots, \nabla F^m(x_0))$ is trivially true. I just wanted to clarify. Thank you so much for all your help! You helped me to understand some difficult and unclear moments.